# How can i go to the latest DetailView when i click action button of push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i am working with a nav based app. and now i m working with push notifications. i know that when i ll click the action button of notification, this method ll b called: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: my question is that is there any way that when i click the action button in notification. My latest feed items detailView ll b opened instead of tableView. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, tell your navigationController to push your detail view controller. That way when the application launches from the push notification, you'll see the detail view like you want.

Comment: when i ll get the notification it should parse feed again otherwise how ll i get the latest item. and detailView of that item is not in the navitionController stack bcz its not generated. So here is my question how can i do that? Generate detailView of new item and then push it in navigationController stack.

Comment: can we check programatically that app is terminated or not?

Comment: Check out Foursquare, it does what you're talking about. When you click on a push notification, it launches the app in a detail venue's detail view. That detail view then asynchronously fetches the information to populate that detail view.